# login to youtube via tor browser

Tags: login

Can my account and password be hacked after logging in to youtube?

And will Tor no longer be anonymous forever or when closing and reopening tor returns to operating securely and anonymously without any trace?

And a small question if I edit TOR so that EntryNodes MiddleNodes and ExitNodes
Will be on the same country that all three servers of a column will be the same country Will a TOR be less anonymous ?

Answer (score 0):

its me i just edit : column = Tor
so every time you see the word "column" change it to "Tor"
Sorry for the inconvenience